# Her upper body is his lower body

Tags: riddle, language

He and she are the opposite.
But her upper body is his lower body.
If the upper body is him, the lower body is her.
When they cross the sea, the two become humans with the same tail.

Who are they?

Note: This riddle is from **Japan**, specifically, a book in the [S&M series](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%26M%E3%82%B7%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA)

Hint:

> If you cross the sea from Japan, you arrive in US - and US uses English.

> What would it take to make the word ‘run’ or ‘swim’ a person?

Come to think now, 2nd and 3rd clues are almost impossible to solve for an English native… I’ll give an explanation if someone  gets the right answer!

Comment: As the riddle is tagged [tag:language] and you mention Japan, does this require any knowledge of Japanese language?

Comment: Yes, a little - but I think one can reach the answer without it and reversely check.

Comment: Right off the bat, it seems the solution is rot13(Lva naq Lnat), but I don't fully see how that goes along with the fourth clue.